# Use default button when pressing enter, but multiline for pasting values

Tags: wpf

In my WPF xaml file, how do I make it so that my textbox uses the default button when I press the return key, but if I paste something in with more than 1 line, it pastes it all in. The AcceptsReturn parameter doesn't let me use a default button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't have similar support as in the WinForms `DialogResult` property.  If you want to do something when someone presses enter then you should override the `OnKeyUp` event or `OnPreviewKeyUp` event.

The `AcceptsReturn` property of the `TextBox` class just means that it will allow the user to press return and register a CRLF in the textbox (otherwise it ignores them).